# Folder cross reference in a Python project

Tags: python, path, reference, code-organization, project-structure

I have a Python project folder which looks something like this:

```
|- main.py
|- data
|- out
|- tests
|- src
   |- utils
   |- etc...
```

Now imagine that inside the source code in `src` I need to continuously reference to the data folder (e.g. I have some dataset in a fixed location to load with a data loader in `utils`), or the output folder. What is the best way to go about this?

#### i) Not working solution

The first solution that comes to mind is to do something like:

```
data_dir = './data'
with open(data_dir + 'file.txt') ...
```

The reference is relative to `main.py`, since I always expect code to be launched from there. However, this is not always the case, as I could for example launch a test from the relative folder.

#### ii) Working inelegant solution

The second solution is to, in every file in `src`, do something like

```
import os

this_file = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

and from here reference the folder you need relative to the file, not depending on where it was launched from (test, main, etc...). This is ok, but I feel like it's not very elegant, requires too many lines of code and need to be changed in **every** file if the data folder changes position (though, I assume pretty static folder organisation for now).

#### iii) My solution

My current solution is the following: create a file `src/utils/project_vars.py` which only contains the absolute paths to some fixed folders. It looks something like:

```
import os

# use to find all absolute paths relative to this file
_file_abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)

# absolute paths of some folders
SRC_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(_file_abspath))
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(SRC_DIR),
    'data'
)
OUT_DIR = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(SRC_DIR),
    'out'
)
```

To find the data folder inside any script in the project I just need to import the `DATA_DIR` variable from here and then use it. Another important advantage is that this solution can be used across platform, e.g. on the cluster I run computations on as well as in local.

**Question**: is there a way to handle this kind of situations organically, such that references remain solid across platforms? Are there common patterns that are usually employed?